# Bind dynamic inputs

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core

I have a form that has a dynamic inputs, so I don't know the count and names of the inputs, as you can see in the code below, they came from database.

```
 <div class="panel-body">
    <form asp-action="BrandFilter" method="get">
        <div class="form-group">
            @foreach (var brand in Model)
            {
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label>
                        <input asp-for="@brand" type="checkbox" />@brand (10)
                    </label>
                </div>
            }
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Apply</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

The question is how to bind all inputs when form is submitted.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> BrandFilter( /* ??? /*)
```

Comment: One option is using editor templates.

Comment: I don't think that can help me in this case.

Comment: why do you think so ?

Comment: Because I can't understand how editor template is useful in this case, if you think so answer the question and show me how with example. :)

Comment: What is `@brand` in your case? Could you show us the Model  and the @Model of your view? I guess that you would like to pass List<Model> to controller?

Comment: Model is IEnumerable<string>, so the brand is string e.g. "Adidas", "Nike" and so on. I will check your answer later cuz i'm tired right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I create a demo that you could select the brands and pass all checkboxes' values to controller.

1.Brand.cs

```
public class Brand
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Selected { get; set; }
}
```

2.View

```
@model List<Models.Brand>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <form asp-action="BrandFilter" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">

            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
            {
                <div class="checkbox">
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].Name)
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m[i].Selected)
                    @Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i].Name)
                </div>
            }

        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

3.controller

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> BrandFilter(List<Brand> brands)
```

Answer (score 0):

The above answer actually works, but I have found also an another approach.

In CSHTML file:

```
<input name="@brand.Name" type="checkbox" value="true"/>@brand.Name (@brand.Count)
```

Method signature:

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> BrandFilter(Dictionary<string, bool> brands)
```

In this approach you are receiving only the checked inputs which leads to a way less data sent to the server.

So instead of posting another question, comment under this answer and say What do you think for both approaches and which one is better?