# Posting the value of the checkbox for a list of items

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm still new in learning asp.net core, and I'm facing this problem with checkboxes. I have a list of items (courses), which are by the way stored in a sql table, and I'm displaying them in a table inside the view, I added the below piece of code for the checkbox but it's not posting any value. I've tried a lot of complicated solutions but none of them worked in my case, so any help would be highly appreciated.

- view:

> ```
> @foreach (Course course in Model)
> {
>    <tr>
>       <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => course.isSelected)</td>
>    </tr>
> }
> ```

---

- Model (Course) has the following property:

> ```
>   [DefaultValue(false)]
>   public bool isSelected { get; set; }
> ```

---

- Controller:

> ```
>         public async Task<ActionResult> Index(string searchString)
>         {
>             var courses = from m in _context.Courses
>                             select m;
>
>             ViewData["Filtering"] = searchString;
>
>             if (searchString != null)
>             {
>                 courses = courses.Where(m => m.Name.Contains(searchString.ToUpper().Replace(" ", "")));
>             }
>             return View(await courses.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync());
>         }
> ```

Comment: What does your controller look like?  So far this code works for me.

Comment: It gets values from a search box and filters the items. So actually it doesn't do anything related to the checkboxes.

Comment: I would not use this `Html helper`, write the whole checkbox tag yourself and pass unique `name` attribute to each single checkbox and show by debugging what does your `Controller` get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to post list of checkbox value to `HttpPost` action, you could use set the same `name`attribute for each checkbox, refer to my demo:

1.View(use a form tag)

```
<form method="post">
  @foreach (Course course in Model)
  {
     <tr>
        <td> <input type="checkbox" name="courseSelectedStatus" value="@course.isSelected" />
     </tr>
  }
  <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

2.Action:

```
[HttpPost]
 public async Task<IActionResult> Index(List<bool> courseSelectedStatus)
    {
       //other logic
        return View();
    }
```

Since it is not clear how do you handle the checkbox value,you could also refer to below link which pass the data in List model:

[Bind dynamic inputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53255850/bind-dynamic-inputs/53259658#53259658)

Update(7/24/2019):

> Is it possible for the value of the checkbox to store an in (the id of the course), so in the controller, I can loop over each int i and change the value of "isSelected", for the course having id = i, into true? (As long the checkbox can store an int value whenever it is checked)

Yes, you could set checkbox value as Id and receive as List in the controller,refer to my below code:

1.View:

```
 <form method="post">
  @foreach (Course course in Model)
  {
     <tr>
        <td> <input type="checkbox" name="courseSelectedStatus" value="@course.Id" />
     </tr>
  }
  <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

2.Action:

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index(List<int> courseSelectedStatus)
    {
        foreach(var i in courseSelectedStatus)
        {
            var employee = await _context.Courses.Where(e => e.Id == i).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
            employee.isSelected = true;
            _context.Update(employee);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        //other logic
    }
```

Comment: Is it possible for the value of the checkbox to store an in (the id of the course), so in the controller, I can loop over each int i and change the value of "isSelected", for the course having id = i, into true? (As long the checkbox can store an int value whenever it is checked)

Comment: @Mohammed Ezzeddine Yes,it is a good solution.please see my edited answer.

Comment: Oh, Thanks a lot. That was helpful!